# SUM of case when GroupBy joining two tables in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two tables and I am trying to get percent of sales for:

- specific ID
- Region
- Brand
- Code
- Start_dt

I am trying to achieve this in PySpark. I tried joining the tables together and filtering the rows, but was unable to include both on and off conditions and divide them to get percentage in one code.

[image: TABLE 2]

[image: Table 1]

I am trying to get percent of sales for ON/ OFF. I have tried something like this but it is only giving me columns that are GroupedBy.

```
#main_df is joined dataframe for table1 and table2
    main_df = main_df.withColumn('value',
                                 F.when((main_df.ON/OFF == 'O'), main_df.PREM_EXTD_RSQTY).otherwise(0)) \
        .groupBy("START_DT",
                 "ON/OFF",
                 "code",
                 "ID", "Region") \
        .agg(F.sum('value').alias('sum'))
```

Equivalent SQL would be something like this

```
SELECT T1.*,
(sum(case when ON/OFF = 'O' THEN Sales_qty else 0 end)/sum(Sales_qty)) as Percent_on_qty,
(sum(case when ON/OFF = 'F' THEN Sales_qty else 0 end)/sum(Sales_qty)) as Percent_off_qty
    from Table1 t1
    left join table2 t2
    on t1.id = t2.id
    and t1.Region = t2.region
    and t1.brand = t2.brnd
    and t1.code = t2.code
    and t1.start_dt = t2.start_dt
    group by t1.id, t1.region, t1.brand,t1.code, t1.start_dt
```

Comment: have you tried any piece of code that did not work and we can help with?

Comment: `spark.sql()` will let you use your sql-query.

Comment: Added my code @samkart

Comment: I need to write it in a python file that has all the PySpark transforms. @qaziqarta

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you right, you want something like this:

```py
df = (
    df_1.join(
        df_2,
        (df_1.ID == df_2.ID)
        & (df_1.Region == df_2.Region)
        & (df_1.Brand == df_2.Brand)
        & (df_1.Code == df_2.Code)
        & (df_1.Start_dt == df_2.Start_dt),
        "left",
    )
    .groupBy(["df_1.ID", "df_1.Region", "df_1.Code", "df_1.Brand"])
    .pivot("df_1.ON/OFF")
    .agg(F.sum("Sales_QTY"))
    .withColumn("Total", F.col("O") + F.col("F"))
    .withColumn("Percent_on_qty", F.col("O") / F.col("Total"))
    .withColumn("Percent_off_qty", F.col("F") / F.col("Total"))
)
```

Which gives:

```
+---+------+-----+-----+---+---+-----+------------------+-------------------+   
|ID |Region|Code |Brand|F  |O  |Total|Percent_on_qty    |Percent_off_qty    |
+---+------+-----+-----+---+---+-----+------------------+-------------------+
|2  |LO    |57868|BC   |699|678|1377 |0.4923747276688453|0.5076252723311547 |
|3  |GO    |87392|DL   |88 |550|638  |0.8620689655172413|0.13793103448275862|
|1  |CA    |98778|AB   |9  |167|176  |0.9488636363636364|0.05113636363636364|
+---+------+-----+-----+---+---+-----+------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks @vladsiv, I have more columns in df_1. If I group by only few columns the resulting dataframe is not having all the columns. How to keep all the records and columns even after the group by and aggregation?

Comment: You're welcome @ShivaGolla. If the column values are the same for a particular ID (just like Brand and Code are the same) you can group by them also, but if they are not you'll have to aggregate and create array or map to preserve the values. If I'm not clear, please update the question and I'll try to correct my answer.